# Images not showing with Cordova ios build

Tags: ios, cordova

My images are not showing in my mobile cordova build and I would appreciate any help. In Phonegap it's required to place [images in the root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607284/images-not-showing-in-phonegap-build-application). Is that the case with Cordova as well?

My structure is the following:

```
/www
   index.html
       /assets
           /img
```

I'm calling image like this from my index.html file:

```
<img src="assets/img/myfile.png" />
```

Is there a reason images won't load? I've checked file permissions. My guess is that I need to make a change in my config.xml. Are these "allow/access" rules sufficient?

```
  <allow-navigation href="file://*/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="file://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
  <access origin="file://*/*"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
```

Comment: Have you emulated you app in safari with ios emulator?

Comment: @HarishKommuri - that's the weird thing. When I use the emulator it works fine, but when I run it on a real device then it doesn't want to show the images.

Comment: Ok. As per my experience, the behavior of package in emulator and device is different. But when you come to iOS, almost everything goes same in emulator and device. I don't why it was happened.

Comment: I had the same issue.  The images were working fine and all of sudden disappeared.  I fixed it by entering Xcode and doing a clean from the product menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, don't forget to add the images to the solution, not just drop them into the correct folder.  If they're not part of the solution, they can't be bundled during the art asset compilation and thus won't show up on deployment.