# Cordova incorrectly resolving paths of image elements constructed during Javascript execution

Tags: reactjs, cordova, create-react-app

I'm trying to build a cross platform app with Cordova and React. However I'm having a hard time getting the app to consistently find images from `www` whose paths are defined in JSX.

**Setup**

- I bootstrapped the react app using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).
- I have set up my CSP and config.xml as required

  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://fonts.googleapis.com file: data: content; media-src *; img-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' file: data: content:; connect-src https://example.com 'self' ws:; font-src https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com 'self'">`

  Don't worry, I'll restrict this once I have the app working.

**Investigation thus far**

- The app loads external images successfully
- If I set the same image path in `index.html` as `<img src="static/media/my_image.becd5aba.jpg"/>` then the image loads fine.
- If I import the image and set it as the src in JSX, it doesn't load.
- If I import the image and trim the leading `/` in JSX to create a relative path, it doesn't load.
- If I hardcode the relative path `static/media/my_image.becd5aba.jpg` in JSX, it doesn't load.
- Inspecting these two elements using the Safari inspector for my iOS sim gives the following paths

  - Image that displays from index.html:

    - Path defined in index.html markup `static/media/my_image.becd5aba.jpg`
    - Path found in inspector `file:///Users/anthonymanning-franklin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/SOME-BIG-PATH-STUFF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/MORE-PATH-GUFF/MyApp.app/www/static/media/my_image.becd5aba.jpg`
  - Image that doesn't display:

    - Path defined in JSX `static/media/my_image.becd5aba.jpg`
    - Path rendered at runtime `file:///static/media/my_image.becd5aba.jpg`

**Potential solutions**

1. Does Cordova run a webserver or am I literally browsing the filesystem in the webview? It looks like the issue is to do with relative paths not resolving correctly in the file system context, so it looks at `file:///static` instead of `file://path/to/application/static/`.
2. I've tried the following

   ```
   import myImage from './../../assets/my_image.jpg'

   let cordova = window.cordova;
   ...
   <img src={`${cordova.file.applicationDirectory}${myImage}`}/>
   ```

But I get a React error

> Attempted to update component `V` that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount).

I guess I need some sort of effective way of referencing the full path in Javascript at run time.

**Similar issues**

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923973/2935062) answer is someone experiencing the same issue, and the accepted answer on this page doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out solution #2 was on the right track.

`cordova.file.applicationDirectory` gives me the right path to the app root but it required the following steps:

1. Install the plugin with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`
2. Ensure you have `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` in `index.html`
3. Ensure your React code begins after `deviceready`. In my case I set `index.js` to the following:

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import './css/index.css';
   import App from './App';
   import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

   document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
     ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
     registerServiceWorker();
   }, false);
   ```

Then created a cordova_globals.js file as such:

```
let FILE_PATH = '';

document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
  FILE_PATH = `${window.cordova.file.applicationDirectory}www`;
}, false);

export {FILE_PATH};
```

Now in my JSX I can reference local images as such:

```
import {FILE_PATH} from 'cordova_globals.js'

<img src={`${FILE_PATH}${myImage}`}/>
```